# How to solve this equilibrium equation for a scarf joint?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, stress-strain

I was reading a book on bonded joint analysis and it references [Erdogan and Ratwani 1971](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/002199837100500308). On page 11 of this paper they write an equilibrium equation from their freebody diagram. I don't understand how they arrived at this equation. I've included pictures of the equations and freebody diagram from the paper as well as two different attempts I made to get to their answer. In particular, I don't understand the division by cosine(alpha) in equation (20)):

$$\phi(x)=\int_0^X (p(t)sin(\alpha)+q(t)cos(\alpha))\frac{dt}{cos(\alpha)}$$

[image: Snippets from Erdogan and Ratwani 1971]

[image: My first attempt]

[image: My second attempt]

Answer (score 0):

It is integral along the skewed line. Each infinitesimal segment ${\rm d}s$ is related to the coordinate direction ${\rm d}x$ with

$$ {\rm d}s = \frac{1}{\cos \alpha} {\rm d}x $$

you can see that from the triangle in the last picture in your posting.

So the line integral $\int \square {\rm d}s$ becomes $$\int \square \frac{1}{\cos \alpha} {\rm d}x $$

Comment: I agree with your integral, the cosine of the angle alpha is equal to the horizontal length divided by the skewed length. 

But that isn’t what is in the paper. Using your parlance of ds and dx (instead of dt and dx), the paper seems to have:

$$dx=\frac{1}{cos(\alpha)}ds$$

You can see in subfigure (c) that dt is parallel to the scarf angle, while dx is parallel to the horizontal, but equation (20) has dt/cos(alpha).

Comment: @wafflerabbit - I see your point. Sorry, I am not that familiar with this specific example, nor its nomenclature.